# Need help setting up test class

Tags: unit-test

Below is my attempt at a test class. I get an error "List Index Out of Bounds: 0"  . Anyone know why and what to do next?

This is my controller.

```
public class vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule {

    //This next line allows this controller to pass data to the VF page vf_BOG_Committee_Report.vfp
    public String htmlCode { get; private set;} 
    public Id oppid{get;set;}
    public boolean ShowLogin {get; set;}
    public boolean ShowTrainingSchedule {get; set;}
//    public String usrEmail {get; set;}
    String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
    User activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : userName limit 1];
    String usrEmail = activeUser.Email;
    List<Additional_Contact_Role__c> cr;
    Public List<Contact> c;
    List<Additional_Contact_Role__c> posList = new List<Additional_Contact_Role__c>();        

public vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule() 
    { 
    //  ID usrID = UserInfo.getUserId();
//        Id userId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');

    //  First show login screen and hide student schedule section
        showLogin = true;
        showTrainingSchedule = false;      
        lookupUser();  
    }

    public void lookupUser()
    {
        // Get the user's email
        c = [select ID,Name, Primary_phone__c, Primary_email__c,Picture__c from Contact where Email = : usrEmail limit 1];        

        if (c.size() > 0) 
        {
            showSchedule(c);
            showLogin = false;
            showTrainingSchedule = true;               
        }else
        {
            htmlCode = 'We are sorry but we can not find that email in our system. Please <a href="http://fullsb-jasmindev.cs18.force.com/sss/vf_Show_Training_Schedule">try again</a>';
            showLogin = false;
            showTrainingSchedule = true;               

        }

    }
    public void cancelAction()
        { 
        }  
    public void showSchedule(List <Contact> c)
    {
        //Set the default year to the current year
        Integer currentYear = System.Today().year();    

        // Get all records from training object for current user
        List<Training__c> queryList = [Select ID,shlch__r.FirstName, Name, Start_Date__c,Start_Time__c,End_Time__c,Trainer__c
                            FROM Training__c 
                            WHERE shlch__r.Primary_email__c = :usrEmail AND shlch__r.name like '%community%' AND shlch__r.Active_Candidate__c = True
                            ORDER BY Start_Date__c,Start_Time__c]; 
        DateTime prevStartDate = DateTime.now();
        DateTime currStartDate = DateTime.now();

        Integer cntNumMemberships=0;
//        htmlCode =''; // The variable we return to the VF page
        String currRecord = '';

        htmlCode = '<style>table, th, td {  padding: 2px;  text-align: left; width: 60%;}</style>';     
        htmlCode = htmlCode+ '<h3>Hi ' + queryList[0].shlch__r.FirstName   + '!</h3> <br /><br />Welcome to the Mishlachat shlchtim 2016 and welcome to Jasmin – a special Salesforce based program developed to support the shlchtut program! <br /> <br /> Below is your shlchtut details as well as your training schedule. Most of the information is hyper-linked and by clicking on it you can get extra details of your shlchtut. <table id="tbl1"> '; //wrap info in HTML table in a table to dispaly properly

        // Generate the shlch and Organization section fields from Position__c
        // Get the Position__c info to show to the user
//Contact__c,shlchtut_Coordinator__c, shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c, Melaveh__c, Organization__c,faffi_Region__c, Region_Manager__c, Region_Manager_Email__c, shlchs_Supervisor__c, Fx_Supervisor_Email__c, Fx_Supervisor_Phone__c

        posList = [select Contact__c,shlchtut_Coordinator__r.Name, shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c, shlchtut_Coordinator__r.MobilePhone, Melaveh__r.Name, Organization__r.Name,faffi_Region__c, Region_Manager__c, Region_Manager_Email__c, shlchs_Supervisor__r.Name, Fx_Supervisor_Email__c, Fx_Supervisor_Phone__c, Organization__r.faffi_Region__r.Manager__r.Primary_phone__c
                                               from Additional_Contact_Role__c 
                                               where Additional_Contact_Role__c.Contact__c = : c[0].id
                                                AND CALENDAR_YEAR(From_Date__c) = :currentYear
                                               ORDER BY Id 
                                               DESC ];        

        // Add Position__c info to HTML table
// TEMP Horizontal Display data     htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table><br /><br /><br /><table><tr><h4><u>faffi Coordinator Info:</u></h4></tr><tr><th>shlchtut Coordinator Name</th><th>shlchtut Coordinator Email</th><th>Melaveh</th><th>Org Name</th><th>faffi Region</th><th>Region Manager</th><th>Region Manager Email</th><th>shlch Supervisor</th><th>shlch Supervisor Email</th><th>shlch Supervisior Phone</th></tr><tr>'  + '<td>'+ cr[0].shlchtut_Coordinator__r.Name +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].Melaveh__r.Name +'</td><td>'+ +cr[0].Organization__r.Name +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].faffi_Region__c+'</td><td>'+ cr[0].Region_Manager__c +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].Region_Manager_Email__c +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].shlchs_Supervisor__r.Name +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].Fx_Supervisor_Email__c +'</td><td>'+ cr[0].Fx_Supervisor_Phone__c +'</td></tr>';          
        htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table><br /><br /><br /><table><tr><th><u>Section A – Personal Info:</u></th></tr><tr><th>shlch – Name</th><td>'+ c[0].Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>Picture</th><td>'+ c[0].Picture__c +'</td></tr><tr><th>Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ c[0].Primary_email__c +'">'+ c[0].Primary_email__c +'</a></td></tr><tr><th>Phone</th><td>'+c[0].Primary_phone__c +'</td></tr</table><br /><br /><br /><table><tr><th><u>Section B – shlchtut Info:</u></th></tr>' ;

        for(Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : posList)
        {


//TEMP          htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table><br /><br /><br /><table><tr><th><u>Section B – shlchtut Info:</u></th></tr><tr><th>Org Name</th><td>' +cr[0].Organization__r.Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>faffi Region</th><td>'+ cr[0].faffi_Region__c+'</td></tr><tr><th>Region Manager</th><td>'+ cr[0].Region_Manager__c +'</td></tr><tr><th>Region Manager Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ cr[0].Region_Manager_Email__c +'">'+ cr[0].Region_Manager_Email__c +'</a></td></tr><tr><th>shlch Supervisor</th><td>'+ cr[0].shlchs_Supervisor__r.Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>shlch Supervisor Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ cr[0].Fx_Supervisor_Email__c +'">'+ cr[0].Fx_Supervisor_Email__c +'</a></td></tr><tr><th>shlch Supervisior Phone</th><td>'+ cr[0].Fx_Supervisor_Phone__c +'</td></tr><tr><th>Melaveh</th><td>'+ cr[0].Melaveh__r.Name+'</td></tr><tr><th>shlchtut Coordinator Name</th><td>'+ cr[0].shlchtut_Coordinator__r.Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>shlchtut Coordinator Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ cr[0].shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c +'">'+ cr[0].shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c +'</a></td></tr>' ;        
            htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><th style="font-size:15px">Org Name</th><td style="font-size:15px">' +cr.Organization__r.Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>faffi Region</th><td>'+ cr.faffi_Region__c+'</td></tr><tr><th>Region Manager</th><td>'+ cr.Region_Manager__c +'</td></tr><tr><th>Region Manager Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ cr.Region_Manager_Email__c +'">'+ cr.Region_Manager_Email__c +'</a></td></tr><tr><th>Region Manager Phone</th><td>'+ cr.Organization__r.faffi_Region__r.Manager__r.Primary_phone__c+'</td></tr><tr><th>shlch Supervisor</th><td>'+ cr.shlchs_Supervisor__r.Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>shlch Supervisor Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ cr.Fx_Supervisor_Email__c +'">'+ cr.Fx_Supervisor_Email__c +'</a></td></tr><tr><th>shlch Supervisior Phone</th><td>'+ cr.Fx_Supervisor_Phone__c +'</td></tr><tr><th>Melaveh</th><td>'+ cr.Melaveh__r.Name+'</td></tr><tr><th>shlchtut Coordinator Name</th><td>'+ cr.shlchtut_Coordinator__r.Name +'</td></tr><tr><th>shlchtut Coordinator Email</th><td><a href="mailto:'+ cr.shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c +'">'+ cr.shlchtut_Coordinator_Email__c +'</a></td></tr><tr><th>shlchtut Coordinator Cell Phone</th><td>'+ cr.shlchtut_Coordinator__r.MobilePhone +'</td></tr>';                   
        }        


        // Replace Null values with N/A so it looks nicer
        htmlCode = htmlCode.replace('null', 'N/A');

        htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table><hr /><table><tr><th><u>Class Schedule:</u></th></tr>';

// Generate the student schedule        
          for(Training__c record :queryList)
          { 
              currStartDate = record.Start_Date__c;
              if (currStartDate.Date() == prevStartDate.date())
                {
                    htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><td><a href="/'+record.Id+'">'+ record.Name +'</a></td>'+ '<td>'+ record.Start_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ record.End_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td></tr>';          
                }
              else
              {
                  htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table><table><tr><th>For the Date of: '+currStartDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd') +'</th></tr><tr><th>Class Name</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th></tr><tr><td><a href="/'+record.Id+'">'+ record.Name +'</a></td>'+ '<td>'+ record.Start_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ record.End_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td></tr>';          
              }  
            prevStartDate = record.Start_Date__c;

        } 
        htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table>'; 

    }
}
```

And this is my first attempt at a test class for it.

```
    @isTest
public class test_Show_Training_Schedule 
{
    @testSetup static void test_Show_Schedule()
    {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name='Jas Training Ctr';
        insert account;

        Contact contactPerson = new Contact();
        contactPerson.FirstName = 'communitytest747';
        contactPerson.LastName = 'communitytest747';
        contactPerson.Accountid = account.id;
        contactPerson.Email='alexf@faffi.org';
        insert contactPerson;

        Contact contactInterviewer = new Contact();
        contactInterviewer.FirstName = 'communitytest2';
        contactInterviewer.LastName = 'communitytest2';
        contactInterviewer.Accountid = account.id;
        insert contactInterviewer;

        List <Training_Resource__c> trL = New List<Training_Resource__c>();

        Integer x;
        for (x=1;x<3;x++)
        {    
            Training_Resource__c tr = New Training_Resource__c();
            tr.Name = 'Test'+x;
            trL.add(tr);

        }
        insert trL;

        LIST <Training__c> trnLst = new LIST <Training__c>();

        for (x=0;x<5;x++)
        {
            Training__c trn = new Training__c();
            trn.name = 'train'+x;
            trn.Shaliach__c = contactPerson.Id;
            trn.Training_Resource__c= trnLst[x].id;

            trnLst.add(trn);    
        }
        insert trnLst;
                Additional_Contact_Role__c acr =  New Additional_Contact_Role__c();
        acr.Name='TestACR';
        acr.recordtypeid = '012G0000001IhYR';
        acr.contact__c = contactInterviewer.id;
        acr.Active__c = True;
        acr.From_Date__c = system.today();
        insert acr;    
    }

          static testMethod void test_Show_Training_Schedule()
          {
              Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.vf_Show_Training_Schedule'));
              vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule controller;

              LIST <Additional_Contact_Role__c> crList = [SELECT ID From Additional_Contact_Role__c];

              Apexpages.StandardController sc = New apexpages.StandardController(crList);                               

              Test.startTest();        

                String userName = 'communitytest747 communitytest747';      
                String c='alexf@faffi.org';
                controller.lookupUser();          
                controller = new vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule();              
                controller.htmlCode = 'test';            

              Test.stopTest();        
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is with this section of code here:

```
    for (x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        Training__c trn = new Training__c();
        trn.name = 'train'+x;
        trn.Shaliach__c = contactPerson.Id;
        trn.Training_Resource__c= trnLst[x].id;  <<----This line here

        trnLst.add(trn);    
    }
    insert trnLst;
```

In the above you've made a self reference to trnLst[x] and it's id before you've inserted it. You can't assign it's Id when it hasn't been inserted. You could reverse the line to `trnLst[x].id == trn.Training_Resource__c;` AFTER you've added `trn` to `trnLst`. But at that point in your code, trnLst[x].id doesn't exist for assignment since it hasn't been inserted, thus the list exception.

You may also want to note that the `trn` has a length of 2 while `trnLst` has a length of 4. You want both lists to have the same length for your code to work.